# Python function returning empty dataframe

Tags: python, function, dataframe

I would like to make a function to create a dataframe using other DataFrames & some filters. My problem : When I apply the function, the output dataframe is empty... yet when i write the code without the loop and the function, it works, I do not understand, i tried to change return position but that doesn't work

First i am creating an empty dataframe -

```
df_Summary=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Country', 'population', 'average age', 'avg salary'])
```

Then i am defining a function with two parameters - 'df' & 'fieldname'. I am using a keyword argument with fieldname(using asterisk *) to filter multiple data and append it to output df_Summary

```
  def make_summary(df,*fieldname):
            global df_Summary
            for dfname in df:
                for field in fieldname:
................df_Summary=df_Summary.append(df[df['Country']==fieldname].reset_index().iloc[:,1:7],sort=False)
            return df_Summary

df_Summary_1 = make_summary(df_Exp_Final_IWM,'China','USA')
```

df_Summary_1 is coming as empty Dataframe. The function should return 2 rows from df dataframe for Countries 'USA' & 'China'

Answer (score 0):

not sure about your purpose. If you want to select rows that contain "'USA' or 'China'" in column Country, you can simply do: df[df["Country"].isin(["USA","China"])].

Answer (score 0):

Please change"filename" to "field" in the following line".

From:

```
df_Summary=df_Summary.append(df[df['Country']==fieldname].reset_index().iloc[:,1:7],sort=False)
```

to:

```
df_Summary=df_Summary.append(df[df['Country']==field].reset_index().iloc[:,1:7])
```

This should solve your problem (I removed sort=False because it complained that there is no "sort=False" in append).